# SVG sine-wave animation using paper.js on canvas, alternatives?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, canvas, svg

I am using paper.js to animate my svg image and the problem is canvas performance. So I am inserting svg to html of site, then with a paper.js I am drawing it on canvas and animating. Here is js code.

```
var originalSVG = document.getElementById('news_habaz'),
    pageContainer = document.querySelector('.page-container'),
    context, path, path2, length, length2, height, originalHeight, scaleCanvas;

function drawImg() {
  context = document.getElementById('newsCanvas').getContext('2d');

  originalWidth = originalSVG.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  scaleCanvas = originalWidth / 781;
  height = 2*scaleCanvas;

  console.log(originalSVG.height);
  project.clear();
  project.importSVG(originalSVG);

  paper.view.setCenter(390,350);

  path = project.activeLayer.scale(scaleCanvas).firstChild.children[2].children;
  path2 = project.activeLayer.firstChild.children[1].children;
  length = path.length;
  length2 = path2.length;
}


function onResize(event) {
  drawImg();
}


function onFrame(event) {


  if(pageContainer.classList.contains('news')) {

    for (var k = 0; k < length; k++){
      for (var i = 0; i < path[k].segments.length; i++) {
            var segment = path[k].segments[i];

            var sinus = Math.sin(event.time*1.5 + i/2);
        var cosinus = Math.cos(event.time + i/4);

        segment.point.y = segment.point.y + sinus* height/7;
        segment.point.x = segment.point.x + sinus* height/8;
        }
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < length2; k++){
      for (var i = 0; i < path2[k].segments.length; i++) {
            var segment = path2[k].segments[i];

            var sinus = Math.sin(event.time*1.5 + i/2);
        var cosinus = Math.cos(event.time + i/4);

        segment.point.y = segment.point.y - sinus* height/9;
        segment.point.x = segment.point.x + sinus* height/6;

        }
    }
  } else {return;}


}

drawImg();

console.log(project.activeLayer.children[0].children[1], path, path[0].segments[0].point.x);
```

It is finding svg, importing. Then drawing it on canvas. When resizing this is done again. 
The most problem is where I click on menu buttons and it is scrolling site, site seems to lag very much. On the other hand when I switch to mobileview, where all sections are visible and scroll by mouse scroll the site is smooth. I am animating it with this fragment of code (on clicking), when it is transforming to the desired section.

```
sectionContainer.css('transform', 'translateY(-' + position*100 + '%)');
```

I added some class to an element on site to see which section is active and only animating the svg on this section. Fragment:

```
if(pageContainer.classList.contains('news'))
```

This helped on desktop Chrome, where the site is a little bit less laggy but still... Unfortunately on Firefox and Mobile devices it doesn't helped.

I know that the canvas is problem, because when I set CSS to `display:none;` site is moving smooth.

Here is a live site where You can see results: http://rafalzwolak.pl/Kreatywni/
Currently only svg on first section is being animated. Original svg is not hidden but it will be.

@edit
if there is some alternative framework or method that will allow me to animate this path svg like sine-waving, please let me know. I know that there is some SVG morphing but morphing 22 paths for each svg and adjusting so much points correctly would be very time consuming.

Comment: On my machine the site seams to run OK. But looking at the time line your page is consuming almost all the available GPU time doing the compositing. This is due to the rasterization of the SVG, your debug console showed 22 layers for the SVG each one being treated like its own canvas (rendered then composited) . As the FX is relatively simple you will get far better performance rendering directly to the canvas, or reduce the number of layers in the SVG.

Comment: Also I just had a look at Paper.js and from their page "Paper.js treats Vector Mathematics as a first class citizen" http://paperjs.org/about/ then I look at their code. https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/basic/Point.js This is not at all what I call optimised or first class.  Try it yourself on the line `segment.point.y= segment.point.y + sinus* height/7;` add a breakpoint then trace into what paper.js has done to it. You will find that it will execute 64 lines (and over ~4 function levels deep I lost count) of code just to do that line. Do you really need to use paper.js?

Comment: @Blindman67 It treats it as such if you use [PaperScript](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscript/) instead of plain Javascript

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Ah so that is optional, gawd why would you want to use that. but still the core paper.js code is more interested in making sure programmers  don't trip up their code with a thick wall of vetting for the most basic operations and then proceed with typical OO inefficiency. First class should mean, trusted, no checking needed, fast code, dirty underbelly, for a sweet clean performant ride on top.

Comment: @Blindman67

Hey, thanks for answers. How could I render it directly to canvas?
Also what does FX stands for?
By compositioning You mean scripting? As I checked timeline in my Chrome Scripting consumes all of CPU and concretely fill function.

And if no paper.js then what could be an alternative to make effect of this kind of waving svg?

Comment: You can render directly using the canvas 2D API  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D FX (effects) refers to the overall animation. Compositing is the process of combining many separate visual layers into one final viewable layer, it is done by the GPU  and initiated explicitly via JS 2D draw calls or implicitly via DOM re-flow (changing SVG content). To do the effect (FX) using JS and 2D API you use the moveTo, bezierCurveTo, quadraticCurveTo, lineTo etc But you will have to write efficiently or you may end up slower, you need to render without the masking